# Problem creating black tinted glass material

Tags: materials, shaders

I was wondering how I can create the black shiny glass material of the container in the following video.

Here is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjWxxcND894

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This should be a very easy material to recreate. What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to create it by using the standard glass shader and then I tried to change the base color to black and finally I played with the options in the Principal shader but in the end, it looked just unrealistic and not good at all. I also tried other things, but unfortunately, I don't remember them. And I'm completely stuck now, don't know from where to start and what to adjust to create this material. I would appreciate it if you can help me!

Comment: Just to add to Leander's super-fast answer: If you're using *Principled* shader, only adjust the roughness and you're done. No need to connect the *Fresnel* node.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like glass. Use a glossy shader.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely try it!

Comment: @Radost Hey :). Please mark the answer as accepted **✓** now, to keep this site nice and tidy. Thanks.

Comment: Done! Thanks again! :3